# Android Studio endlessly says Hyper-V needs to be disabled

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, haxm

Whenever I try to run the emulator in Android studio I get this dialog box:

[image: Android Studio Error]

Since then I have disabled Hyper-V in windows features, and have disabled it from running in my services:

[image: features][image]

I've rebooted many times and have run the command that Android Studio tells me to numerous times as well, but have no luck.  I also have tried to install Intel HAXM separately and get the same message.  I've checked the BIOS and have virtualization enabled wherever there are options. How can Android Studio/HAXM still sense Hyper-V even though it is disabled everywhere?

Comment: Did you find the solution @chadb768?

Comment: The only solution I was able to find was to switch emulators.  Many had a similar problem but I believe it was MEmu that finally worked.